# Xamarin Forms, C# , WebView , Image

Tags: c#, android, webview, xamarin.forms

Hello and Good afternoon, I am stuck again. I want to access Images from the mobile device and populate it on the Xamarin form.However, It is quite easy and I have been able to do along side in asset and resource folder. Since, I am new to Mobile development, I don't know how to set the path and retrieve an image from the device memory(No clue to how it works).Could you please help me with it? The sole idea is to fetch the image from device memory(or SD card).

Comment: Have you done any research at all?

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for exists as a plugin which is called 
[Media Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media/)

You can find more details about it and samples [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)

Comment: I am trying to play a video in Webview and trying to load the video from the Assets folder, but it's not playing.